# Left truncate Scala function - list from integer

Tags: function, scala

I am totally new in Scala, could you help me with the simple function - 
input parameter is an integer, the function should return a list of integers with the first entry is input integer , and the rest are gotten by omitting the left most digit one by one. For example,

if   input is `0`, it  returns `List(0)`, `input =5678` returns `List(5678,678,78,8)`.

```
def leftTrunc(input:Int):List[Int]
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Any attempt from your side?

Comment: Homework question right ?

Comment: By the way I'm not saying that to annoy you, but you will learn more by  trying it yourself  and then come here to ask what's the problem with your solution, if any.

Comment: What's supposed to happen with negative numbers?

Comment: @Alexis C - I should've put my code into the question, agree

Answer (score 2):

```
5678.toString.tails.toList.init.map(_.toInt)

//> res0: List[Int] = List(5678, 678, 78, 8)
```

Convert the number to a String. Then `tails` does exactly what you want. Except it's an iterator, so convert it to a `List`, and also it has an empty string at the end, so use `init` to return all but the last element. But they're strings, so use `map` to convert them all to `Int` again

But I'm pretty sure your instructor is expecting you to do it numerically :)

Here's a numerical version, in this case deliberately uncommented so you can work out for yourself how it works

```
val n = 5678 
val digits = n.toString.size
List.iterate(10, digits)(10*) map { n % _}
```

EDIT: As requested in the comment, the other way around just uses inits instead of tails (and a reverse to get the requested ordering)

```
5678.toString.inits.toList.init.reverse.map(_.toInt)
//> res0: List[Int] = List(5, 56, 567, 5678)
```

And the numerical one is easier this way around

```
List.iterate(n, digits)(_/10).reverse
```

Comment: Scala is simply amazing. :) `tails` makes perfect sense.

Comment: Curious, if we wanted `List(5, 56, 567, 5678)`, how'd you do it?

Comment: @Paul Thanks a lot, I was trying in the right direction, did realize how to use map

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot of fun if you share your attempt, and we all can give our attempts too. :) I hope you've got some and here's a couple of ideas form my end...

```
"5678".foldRight(Seq[String](""))((c, s) => s"$c${s.head}" +: s).dropRight(1)

"5678".foldRight(Seq[String]())((c, s) => s"$c${s.headOption.getOrElse("")}" +: s)
```